# Estimote iOS SDK : Eddystone beacon format `didDiscoverEddystones` return empty array and not able to discover beacons in range

Tags: ios, ibeacon, estimote, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

After successfully detecting `iBeacons` from the Esimote SDK, I started working with `Eddystone beacons` in the same SDK with help of

```
<EstimoteSDK/ESTEddystone.h>
```

I provided namespace id in `ESTEddystoneFilterUID` object as below and then started discovering beacons from `startEddystoneDiscoveryWithFilter` method.

```
ESTEddystoneUID *eddystoneUID = [[ESTEddystoneUID alloc] initWithNamespaceID:@"0x2f234454f4911ba9ffa6" instanceID:@"1"];
self.uidFilter = [[ESTEddystoneFilterUID alloc] initWithUID:eddystoneUID];

[self.eddystoneManager startEddystoneDiscoveryWithFilter:self.uidFilter];
```

Later I came to the delegate `eddystoneManager:didDiscoverEddystones:withFilter` , with empty `eddystones` array. 
[image]

Is there any thing missing? Can anyone please help to get UUID/Name space of beacon in range.

Comment: @davidgyoung Sir, Do you know any solutions?

Comment: Sorry, I am not experienced with the Estimote SDK.

Comment: @davidgyoung thank you for reply..

Answer (score 0):

You should skip the `0x` part in your Namespace ID, Estimote SDK already expects a hex-encoded string. (i.e., you should use `2f234454f4911ba9ffa6`)